# Trying to set up 2 monitors + laptop in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to set up a laptop to be able to work the laptop display and two additional displays. Both displays seem to only work when I close the laptop lid. When the lid is open, only one display will work. I tried going into the Screen Resolution settings in windows 7 but when I enable one monitor for extended desktop then the other monitor becomes disabled automatically. Does anyone know what is going on? One is being plugged in the VGA slot and the other is plugged in through the DisplayPort on the docking station. I also tried using a DVI connector but none seem to work.

Comment: What's your laptop capability?  Some video interface chipsets can only support a maximum number of displays / pixels.  It can work -- my Dell latitude 6XXX w/ Win7 works with 3 displays when connected to the docking station.

Comment: What graphics card is in the laptop?

Comment: Intel HD Graphics 3000

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the answer is **No**; From [Intel's FAQ](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-031040.htm) on the HD 3000:

> Can I output video to three display devices, not just two? No. Intel®
>   graphics products can output to one or two display devices at the same
>   time. More than two display devices can be physically connected, but
>   only two display devices can be used at any time.

Comment: Note that this is no longer true for the newer equipment - you can push three outputs off Haswell-generation Intel GPUs (potentially, assuming appropriate connectivity)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a USB external screen which requires a driver - eg: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824236357
or even three screens: http://www.rugged-portable.com/multi-screen-display-rugged-portables/
(a LOT more money, and overkill for most users)
that way you can have your HD3000 running two screens and the third running over USB. (Preferably USB3)